# How do you add a user control after creating it?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am having trouble adding a UserControl to my main window via Xaml.  Can someone please spell out the steps required to go from the completion of a UserControl class to seeing it appear on my main window.

I have done research on this and found a few plausible ways to approach it:

1) add reference in the top of the main window xaml using namespace and assembly name

2) add reference to window xaml in reference tag

3) create the entire user control in the main window xaml

I would prefer to do it either the second or third way (or another easy way) but cannot find anything to guide me through this process.

Comment: are you creating this `UserControl` at runtime yourself?

Comment: I created the user control (statically) and am just looking for a way to meet the requirements for references as well as the syntax to actually put my user control on a page.

Comment: Is this usercontrol part of the same project or solution as your application?

Comment: The control should be in the VisualStudio toolbox, just drag it onto your page/window and it will create the references for you.

Comment: @sa_ddam213 This was very helpful and by far the easiest solution I was looking for.  Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a user control to window after creating it:

Step1:
Adding reference to the window in xaml:

```
    xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:WpfApplicationName.Views"
```

Step2:
Adding the view to grid/stackpanel/wrappanel

```
    <Grid>
        <Views:UsercontrolName/>
    </Grid>
```

Add this and once build your project.

You usercontrol will be loaded into the window.

Hope this helps you.